# Why won't my python code print anything?

Tags: python

A program I wrote wasn't printing anything when I executed it out of the terminal, so I tried the ran the following code

```
import sys

#!/usr/bin/python

def main(argv):
    print  "hell0\n"
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

[this is the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rud88.png) why is it not printing out hello. Is the main function even running?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python does not automatically call main() (and you'll need to use the sys library to get argv).

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

def main():
    print  "hell0\n"

main()
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't call `main` anywhere, you've only defined it.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:  (1) your `#!/use/bin/python` needs to be the first thing in your file, and (2) you need to add a call to `main`.  As it is, you're defining it, but not actually calling it.

In Python, you would not normally pass command-line arguments to `main`, since they are available in `sys.argv`.  So you would define `main` as not taking any arguments, then call it at the bottom of your file with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

The test for `__name__` prevents `main` from being called if the file is being imported, as opposed to being executed, which is the standard way to handle it.

If you want to explicitly pass the command line arguments to `main`, you can call it as:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

which is what you would need to do with the definition you currently have.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement Oops, the way OP defined `main` you would need to pass arguments. I updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome! Five-year service honor!

Answer (score 1):

In python your code doesn't have to be in a function, and all functions have to be explicitly called.

Try something like this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print  "hell0\n"
```

Comment: The [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) needs to be the very first line of the file.

Answer (score -1):

make sure you call the function after defining it,

defining a function only stores it in memory.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

def main(argv):
    print  "hell0\n"
    sys.stdout.flush()

main()
```

Comment: It looks like his main function expects arguments, but you're not passing them?

Answer (score -1):

usually, people put some code at the end of the script to run the main(), e.g.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then, you can run your script in terminal, and it will call the main() method.

Comment: His main expects arguments, so you'll need to pass those, too, right?